# How can I get duplicate values from ArrayList?

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, duplicates

I have a ArrayList: `ArrayList<String> buffer = new ArrayList<String>();`

How can I take duplicated values from ArrayList?

Example:

```
fsfs.txt
erwre.txt
wery.txt
wtrtr.txt
erwre.txt
qweq.txt
```

My attempts:

With cycles:

```
for(int i = 0; i < buffer.size(); i++) {
    for(int j = i + 1; j < buffer.size(); j++) {
        if( buffer.get(i).equals(buffer.get(j)) ) {
            bufferTemp.add(j, buffer.toString() ); 
            j--;
        }
    }
 }

With iterator:
Iterator<String> i = buffer.iterator();
Iterator<String> j = buffer.iterator();
j.next();
     while(i.hasNext() && j.hasNext()) {
        if( i.next().equals(j.next() )
        System.out.println(i.next());
     }
```

Also I try to use Comparable, Comparator and other ways but it don't work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you correctly, you use Java and want to get the duplicates of an ArrayList.

If you use Strings, then you can just sort the List and compare in a loop the previous with the current element. Look at this (Java 7):

```
ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();

list.add("fsfs.txt");
list.add("erwre.txt");
list.add("wery.txt");
list.add("wtrtr.txt");
list.add("erwre.txt");
list.add("qweq.txt");

// Sort the list
Collections.sort(list);

// Test if List was sorted correctly
for(String s : list)
{
    System.out.println(s);
}

System.out.println("\n*** Now try to get duplicates ***\n");

Iterator<String> listIt = list.iterator();

String prev = "";
boolean foundDuplicate = false;
while(listIt.hasNext())
{
    String current = listIt.next();

    if(current.equals(prev))
        foundDuplicate = true;
    else
        foundDuplicate = false;

    if(foundDuplicate)
    {
        // Duplicate found!
        System.out.println(current);
    }

    prev = current;
}
```

Output should be:

```
erwre.txt
erwre.txt
fsfs.txt
qweq.txt
wery.txt
wtrtr.txt

*** Now try to get duplicates ***

erwre.txt
```

Comment: I have a problem: I enter in collection with help by File :         File[] files = path.listFiles();                                   try {                                                              for (File file : files) {                                          if (file.isDirectory()) { //recursively return file and directory find(file);                                                           } else { buffer.add(file.getName()); ... 'path' - root of files And after sorting, the result: eq fs we er qw wt, because first row from dir "1", and second row from directory in directory "1"

Comment: Please, Can you add your problem with formatted code to the question above or create a new question? Then it will be easier to understand. Is it right, that the result of Collection.sort does not give you the result you want?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22596357/how-can-i-get-duplicated-values-from-arraylist

Answer (score 1):

You can create a Set passing the your list as a argument. Set will take care of duplicates.

```
private static List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

public static void main(String[] args) {

    list.add("aaa.txt");
    list.add("aaa.txt");
    list.add("aaa.txt");
    list.add("bbb.txt");
    list.add("ccc.txt");
    list.add("ccc.txt");

    Set<String> set = new HashSet<String>(list);

    System.out.println(set);
}
```